# Custom sorting in @tanstack/react-table v8

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-table

I have a problem with declaring custom sort types.The documentation states the declaration as follows:

```
declare module '@tanstack/table-core' {
    interface SortingFns {
       myCustomSorting: SortingFn<unknown>
     }
}
```

I did this in an external .d.ts file. But now this property has become mandatory and must now be specified in useReactTable.

```
const instance = useReactTable(
    {
        data,
        columns,
        getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
        sortingFns: {}
    }
)
```

Can I somehow declare it so that it is optional?

Comment: Could you add more detail and give us a more concrete example of a use case in your code?

Comment: Without declaring types I can create a table like this.
`const instance = useReactTable({data, columns, getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel()})`.
But when i adding `declare module`, i must create like this:
`const instance = useReactTable({data, columns, getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(), sortingFns: {...}})`.

sortingFns is no longer an optional property and must be specified

Comment: Add that to your question using the `Edit` option. The best way to get help on here is to ask good question and provide all the possible details and use-cases. Also a `MRE - Minimal reproducible example` is a good option to have on `codesandbox.io`, for example